# How to get specific character in complicated condition

Tags: sql, postgresql, amazon-redshift

I have like following columns.I'd like to get letters after `login_name`

`test_id:taaotai,priority:Primary,login_name:[person1]`

I'd like to get `person1` from above column.

If someone has opinion, please let me know

Answer (score 1):

You can use `substring` with a regex:

```
select substring(login_name from 'login_name:\[(.*)\]')
from your_table
```

Answer (score 0):

Regexp search will do the job.

```sql
select (regexp_matches(
  'test_id:taaotai,priority:Primary,login_name:[person1] and whatever else', 
  '\mlogin_name:\s*\[(.+)\]')
)[1];

-- person1
```